# Mi notificación de bootstrap-notify encima de mi modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

tengo el siguiente inconveniente , quiero ocupar bootstrap-notify para que al momento de validar mis datos en un formulario, dicho formulario es un modal pero al momento de validar me manda la notificación por debajo del modal.

Como se aprecia en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero que nada te faltaría leer [ask] para hacer una buena pregunta; esto para obtener mejor respuesta. Además, es necesario que agregues tu código para localizar posible error en tu código y solucionar. Sin código es difícil resolver. Este sito está basado en compartir códigos para las preguntas y respuestas. Pero como a veces es simple una solución, no se puede responder así por así. Podría deducir que tú problema se soluciona con `z-index`. Pero es una deducción.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La propiedad CSS `z-index` establece el orden `z` de un elemento posicionado y sus descendientes o elementos flexibles.

Si ahora queremos cambiar el orden de apilamiento de estos elementos, podemos usar la propiedad `z-index`. Un elemento con un índice `z` más alto se mostrará delante de un elemento con un índice `z` más bajo. Una cosa a tener en cuenta es que el índice `z` solo funciona con elementos posicionados.

Recuerda tener el estilo del div de notificaciones posicionado con;

```css
// Posición Absolute
.notificacion {
  position: absolute;
}

// Posición Relative
.notificacion {
  position: relative;
}
```

Te dejo este link por si quieres saber más sobre la posición de los elementos;

https://aprende-web.net/css/css7_3.php

Luego lo único que tienes que hacer es poner el estilo del `div` notificación un grado menos que el orden del `modal`.

```css
.modal{
  z-index: 1;
}

.notificacion {
  z-index: 0;
}

.otrocontenido {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

Aquí tienes un simple ejemplo de una notificación en un `modal` de *Bootstrap*, empezar por aquí es una buena opción. Intenta encontrar la solución que más se adapte a tu problema, yo me he basado en la imagen que has adjuntado en tu pregunta.

```css
.notifacion{
margin:20px; 
height:50px;
width:50%;
background-color:blue;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
}

.notifacion-s{
height:50px;
width:100%;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color:#FFB6C1;
border:3px solid red;
z-index:0;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!--https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            <div class="notifacion-s">Error Contraseña, no utilice únicamente números, mayúsculas o minúsculas en su contraseña. No repita caracteres (1111111). </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          
          <div class="notifacion">Notificación</div>
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="notifacion-s">Notificación</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que le haya ayudado.